# Including non-markovian processes in a birth-death process

Tags: stochastic-processes, mathematical-modeling, applications, markov-process

**Current model**

I want to model a stochastic system with a birth-death (Markovian) model. I therefore have this kind of $n$ times $n$ (where $n$ is the number of possible states) transition matrix:

$$\begin{matrix} 
                 1-p & p & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
                 f_{-1}(s,2) & f_{0}(s,i) & f_{+1}(s,i) & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
                 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & f_{-1}(s,i) & f_{0}(s,i) & f_{+1}(s,i)  \\
                 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & p &  1-p  \\
\end{matrix}$$

, where $i$ is the current state (the row in the matrices), $s$ is a parameter and $f_{-1}$, $f_{0}$ and $f_{+1}$ are the functions that compute the probabilities of moving to the lower state, remaining in the same state and moving to the higher state respectively. When the model is at one of the two extreme state ($0$ or $n$), it can only leave this state with probability $p$. Therefore, this model has two absorbing states iff p=0. Typically, for what I want to model $p$ is relatively close to $0$ and I expect the most of the time the system will be at one of the two extreme states.

**Question**

Now, I'd like to extend my model so that the parameter $s$ is drawn from some frequency distribution $F(S=s)$ every time the model leaves (or reach) one of the two extremes states. How can I model such thing? Can I keep using a birth-death markovian model or should necessarily use some other model?

Answer (score 1):

This corresponds to a hidden Markov model $(X_n,S_n)$ where the hidden state $S_n$ determining the transition probabilities from the "non extreme" states is redrawn with the desired distribution $P(S=s)=q(s)$, independently of everything else, each time the observed process $X$ hits the extreme states $0$ and $n$.

Transitions with nonzero probability corresponding to the desired dynamics are the following:

- $(i,s)\to(i,s)$ with probability $f_0(s,i)$, for every $s$, $i\ne0$, $i\ne n$
- $(i,s)\to(i-1,s)$ with probability $f_{-1}(s,i)$, for every $s$, $i\ne0$, $i\ne n$
- $(i,s)\to(i+1,s)$ with probability $f_1(s,i)$, for every $s$, $i\ne 0$, $i\ne n$
- $(0,s)\to(0,s)$ and $(n,s)\to(n,s)$, each with probability $1-p$, for every $s$
- $(0,s)\to(1,t)$ and $(n,s)\to(n-1,t)$, each with probability $pq(t)$, for every $s$ and $t$

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'll have further look to HMM. For the moment I know very little about HMM. I had in mine though that we use HMM when we observe some variable and want to estimate the underlying variable that explain at best the set of observed variable given that there is some transition probability between all discrete states of the hidden variable.

Comment: I am not trying to estimate the value of $s$ but I am trying to calculate the percentage of time that the system spends at a given state given the transition probability and the PDF of $s$. So, can I really do that with HMM? I'll have further look to HMM hoping I can end up figuring out how to implement  my model. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure one can "really do that with HMM" since the observation process X in an HMM is simply the first coordinate of the Markov process (X,S). Basically this is why HMMs were invented, to still be able to use "Markovian" tools in a non Markovian context.

Comment: I still have a hard time understanding how to calculate a stationary distribution for such model. Can you please make an example by choosing some functions for $f_0(..)$, $f_{+1}()$ and $f_{-1}()$ such that $f_0(..)$ + $f_{+1}()$ + $f_{-1}()$ = 1. And choose some distribution from which a new value of the parameter $s$ is drawn every time the system quits one of the "extremities". Such example can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/971097/markov-process-parameters-drawn-from-some-distribution) but the post will probably get deleted following your advice. Thks